# pass data to a servlet

Tags: java, jsf, servlets

Basically we have a JSF app that dynamically generates a link to a servlet, which serves up the PDF file. I need to pass the path of the PDF to the servlet. I have no idea of how to pass data to a servlet.

In the View we have:

```
<d:protocolSection value="#{detailBacker.studyData}" id="protocol" />
```

In the controller we have

```
public string getFile() {
  .......
  // some variable here that holds the folder and file name
  result += "<a href=\"/catalog/catalog/WelcomeServlet\"  target=\"_blank\">" + name + "</a>
  .......
}
```

I basically need to send the variable that holds the folder and file name to the WelcomeServlet somehow so that the WelcomeServlet can use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass it as a request parameter or pathinfo the usual Servlet way.

Here's an example assuming pathinfo is preferred and `#{bean.pdfpath}` returns something like `filename.pdf`:

```xml
<h:outputLink value="pdf/#{bean.pdfpath}">Download pdf</h:outputLink>
```

In the servlet mapped on an URL pattern of `/pdf/*` you can get it as follows in `doGet()` method:

```java
String pdfpath = request.getPathInfo();
// ...
```

As a completely different alternative, you can also just let JSF write the PDF to the response in a commandlink/commandbutton action method.

Comment: I don't see why you would ever generate the view in the controller. Just do the job in the view. If you really *really* insist, you can display it using `<h:outputText value="#{bean.somehtml}" escape="false" />`. But it stinks.

Comment: Well, just set the path there? String concatenation and so on. `"<a href=\"pdf/" + pdfpath + "\" target=\"_blank\">"` and in the servlet get it by `request.getPathInfo()`. See also my answer here above.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Java. Do I need to use a query string?

Comment: You need to make your link look like `<a href="servleturl/filename.pdf">` and you need to ensure that you map the servlet on `/servleturl/*` and you need to get the `/filename.pdf` part by `request.getPathInfo()` in servlet. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

keep the location fixed of generated/created pdf files and just pass the name of file like

```
/pdfServlet?fileName=#{someBean.someFileName}
```

in servlet's `doGet()` retrieve the fileName and serve the file.

```
String fileName = request.getParameter("fileName");
```

Comment: Note that this way causes MSIE to save the file as `pdfServlet` instead of the specified filename. It namely ignores the filename in the content disposition header and takes the last part of the path.

Comment: Now can I actually put that jsf code in a dynamically generated anchor tag? For example I have a controller that is generating the tag this way `result += "<a href=\"/a/b/WelcomeServlet\"  target=\"_blank\">" + name + "</a>`

Comment: @BalusC what if we add headers in servlet ?or simply redirects user to file ?

Comment: @CatFish, yes you can as it will get converted to pure HTML